# Slick slider breaks centered layout when an item is hidden

Tags: javascript, slick.js

I have a Slick carousel centered using the method described [here][1].

However, the layout breaks if there is a hidden carousel item:

```
<div class="slider">
  <div class="hidden"><h3>H</h3></div>
  <div><h3>1</h3></div>
  <div><h3>2</h3></div>
  <div><h3>3</h3></div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/yo58wkt3/

I wish I could change the HTML but the structure is needed by another plugin.

Comment: why not remove the hidden slide before you initialise slick: https://jsfiddle.net/5j8f231g/

Comment: I wish I could but it's needed by the plugin. I've tried moving it to another place in the DOM but it breaks the functionality

Comment: not sure what functionality you can do with a hidden div but your problem is that slick creates it's track width based on the number of children in the div whether they're hidden or not, guess the only other thing would be to reduce the track width on slick init so it didn't include the hidden divs (but if you did this and you have the next and prev buttons, you would get phantom clicks when the active slide is your hidden slide)